# How to get a .java file from an Intellij project?

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea

I don't understand how to get the .java files of the java classes that I have in my intelliJ project.
Does anyone know how?

I checked where it saves projects and found the project folder but there's no java files in it

Thank you

Comment: Java files will be in the source roots: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Answer (score 0):

Your .java files are stored in multiple sub foulders if you're using intelliJ you should look for a folder called scr then go to main and then java there you should see your files. here is the entire path:

./YourProjectDir/src/main/java

Answer (score 0):

In intelliJ you can press Select Opened File button (looks like aim sign) to open your class location. Than you can press on it with right mouse button, select Open In -> Files.
[image]

[image]